# error 1009 in actionscript 3 with instance correctly named in the stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to animate 3 similar texts in 3 frames and the SWF-file works properly but the compiler generates error 1009 every click.
the debug tells me that the problems are in the `.addEventFrame` method of `blocco_anno1` but tracing it, it is recognised as `object MovieClip`.

```
blocco_anno1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entrata1);
blocco_anno1.alpha = 0;

function entrata1(event:Event)
{
    blocco_anno1.alpha += 0.05;
    if(blocco_anno1.alpha >= 1)
    {
        blocco_anno1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entrata1);
    }
}


stop();


comandi.anno2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , function()
{
    blocco_anno1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , da1a2);
    trace(blocco_anno1)
});

function da1a2(event:Event)
{
        blocco_anno1.alpha -= 0.07;
        if(blocco_anno1.alpha <= 0)
        {
            blocco_anno1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, da1a2);
            gotoAndPlay(4);
        }
};


comandi.anno3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , function()
{
    blocco_anno1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , da1a3);
    trace(blocco_anno1)
});

function da1a3(event:Event)
{
        blocco_anno1.alpha -= 0.07;
        if(blocco_anno1.alpha <= 0)
        {
            blocco_anno1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, da1a3);
            gotoAndPlay(5);
        }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide FLA file?

Comment: sure, could you explain me how? I can not find the right button

Comment: Upload to any file sharing web-site.

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!iQ92AYpD!Wh6EPsPfbOH8FPmzxYuJQpxqIWCmdhWx5Kdkqr0-txA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frame 3, layer "corpo", line 28:

```
blocco_anno1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, da1a2);
```

Here should be:

```
blocco_anno1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , da1a2);
```

---

Next. line 36:

```
blocco_anno1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , da1a3);
```

If you click II and then III, code in third frame will be called:

```
comandi.anno3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , function()
{
   blocco_anno1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , da1a3);
});
```

But in fourth frame you haven't `blocco_anno1`.

To fix this avoid use anonymous handlers. You code should be like this:

```
comandi.anno2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAnno2);

function clickAnno2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    blocco_anno1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , da1a2);
}
```

Before call 'gotoAndStop' you should remove all event handlers.

Comment: i forgot to have edited the line 28. the problems were also before this editing. in the fourth frame i have 'blocco_anno2' which appear and disappear as in the fifth I have 'blocco_anno3'

Comment: I fixed your code. See here [http://subdan.ru/work/1.fla](http://subdan.ru/work/1.fla). I placed all code for navigation in the third frame.

Comment: thank you very much, the code is sooo much more efficient!
But i am sorry, the compiler continue to tell error 1009

Comment: Wait when animation complete and then click to II or III. I'll try to fix error 1009. This error appears if you fast switch between screens.

Comment: Add this line: `this["blocco_anno" + currentAnnoID].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this["entrata" + currentAnnoID]);` in each "clickAnno" function before "addEventListener".

Comment: THANK YOU!!! now it works without errors.
one last question: if the program worked but with error 1009, it would be a problem or could i ignore it?

Comment: Any app shouldn't contains any runtime errors even If it works properly. IMO. Don't ignore these errors.